# Is there a shortcut for creating many polygons with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a grid of triangles like in this picture: https://www.tilelook.com/system/tile_picture/resource/4973584/d3d_default_RE04MC017.png.

As i want the triangles to be clickable I'm using canvas function `create_polygon` for drawing and `bind` function for listening to the click event. The problem is that i need to draw many triangles and this would require to calculate by hand the vertices of each triangle.

Is there a faster method like drawing some parallel and intersecting lines and tell tkinter that the vertices are the intersections of the lines or something that doesn't involve calculating the vertices of each triangle?

Comment: I don't see why `tkinter` has to find intersections...You could do that yourself in a function and feed this information to `tkinter`

Comment: I know it can't, in fact it is an example. Do you know if tkinter can give me the intersection of two lines created with `create_line`?

Comment: I am not sure, but you should include the code that uses that function in your question so it is more clear. [A MCVE would be great](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and help the community to help you!

Comment: No, tkinter can't give you the intersection of two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't get the intersections from within `tkinter` you could instead make triangles with a couple `for` loops and then plot these on the canvas. An example would look like:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def make_triangles(row_height=60, tri_width=60, max_height=1800, max_width=1800):
    triangle_list = []
    half_width = int(tri_width/2)
    for i in range(0, max_height, row_height):
        for j in range(0, max_width, half_width):
            if j % tri_width == 0:
                triangle = (i, j-half_width, i+row_height, j, i, j+half_width)
            else:
                triangle = (i, j, i+row_height, j+half_width, i+row_height, j-half_width)
            triangle_list.append(triangle)
    return triangle_list

win = tk.Tk()
canv = tk.Canvas(win)
triangles = make_triangles()
for tri in triangles:
    canv.create_polygon(tri, fill=random.choice(["blue", "red", "green", "brown", "yellow", "black"]))
canv.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Where we just generate many triangles and then plot them successively onto the canvas (we don't have to find each vertex by hand, just a formula that would describe them all). While this doesn't solve your exact problem in that the triangles don't intersect (you would have to shift every other row by half a triangle), and the triangles are left/right instead of up/down, it **does** answer your question "*Is there a shortcut for creating many polygons with tkinter*"! The answer is to just make a list of your polygons and then plot them all. A sample output (yours will be different because it is random) of my code looks like:

[image: Resulting Triangles]

Comment: Thank you, I think that this is the best solution for me. I'll use your function as a starting point for my program.